# External Component Error. Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception

Tags: sitecore-client

Does anyone have faced this issue? I am getting this every time when I build my code. The issue has gone when I do the IIS reset.

Just to let me know guys when I build my code it directly copy the dll to the deployed code. It's nothing to do with licensing. I have checked the license file is at the correct place and still valid (as I mentioned it worked after IIS reset).

[image]

Comment: It looks like some in-memory dump in your code, which clear on your IISRESET I guess. Try to debug your solution and see on which code part you are getting error.

Comment: Can you check in your sitecore logs if there are additional information about the issue?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing this issue right now and I was wondering if you managed to resolved this issue?

Comment: No @ArjenvanVeen, still its not working for me in my machine. But the same is working fine on others machine.

Comment: @SrikantRahul Have you seen this article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/742318 ?Sitecore support brought this to my attention and indeed the "Stackify Prefix profiler" was installed on that particular machine. After uninstalling the exception was gone, hope this helps for you as well! Not sure why that page is not showing up when googling though...